# How to differentiate between ie7 and IE compatibility on higher versions on the server

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

Is it possible to **differentiate between request coming from IE7** and **request coming from higher version of IE running in compatibility mode?**

I would prefer a pure server side solution to something involving JavaScript.

Comment: As I know only one way to get this information is to use User-Agent string, but IE hides it very well, I mean in both cases you will get `MSIE 7.0` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I would argue that it's not worth the effort to try to differentiate them. Yes, there are some notable bugs in compatibility mode that make it different to a real IE7, but in reality, you shouldn't be getting any compatibility mode users anyway unless you're in a corporate environment that mandates it. Assuming you've got the right meta tags in place, you can force IE to avoid compat mode, so any compat mode users you do get will be setting it manually. The only other user who might get compat mode is yourself while testing locally, due to IE's intranet settings. But you can disable that too.

Comment: @Spudley - the problem is because the application is deployed over intranet and IE Compatibility View Settings is overriding all my settings to run the application in compatibility mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check user agent for IE version and Trident version, like in [this article](http://www.toplinestrategies.com/dotneters/net/detecting-ie-compatibility-view-c/?lang=en):

```
string userAgent = Request.UserAgent; //entire UA string
string browser = Request.Browser.Type; //Browser name and Major Version #

if (userAgent.Contains("Trident/5.0")) //IE9 has this token
{
    if (browser == "IE7")
    {
        mode = "IE9 Compatibility View";
    }
    else
    {
        mode = "IE9 Standard";
    }
}
```